# (C++) Creating two dimensional array from .dat file

Tags: c++, arrays, converters

I am trying to define a `class CDTable`, which has a variable `double table[4][4000]` (4 by 4000 array of doubles) and some functions that carry out calculations based on the table.

My CDTable.h looks something like:

```
#define CDTABLE_H
class CDTable {
public:
    double table[4][4000];
    CDTable(string fileName);
    double dLookUp(double z);
};
```

and a part of my CDTable.cpp looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "CDTable.h"

using namespace std;

CDTable::CDTable(string fileName) {
    fstream file;
    file.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::in);
    string line;
    int col = 0;
    int row = 0;

    getline(file, line);    //skip the title line
    while (getline(file, line, '\t')) { //for each line
        istringstream ss(line);
        double val;
        while (ss >> val) {     //read the value
            table[row][col] = val;  //assign the value
            ++col;  //next column in the table
        }
        ++row;  //next line in the table
        col = 0;    //reset column
    }

    file.close();
}

int main() {
    CDTable cd = CDTable("CDLookUp.dat");
    return 0;
}
```

So, I mean to construct a `CDTable` object by giving it a `string fileName` which is a .dat file of two dimensional array (the first line of .dat file is not real data but a title line). I have other relevant methods implemented in CDTable.cpp as well, but I have not included them since they do not seem to be the problem.

CDTable.cpp compiles without any errors, but when I run it, I get Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Can somebody tell me what's wrong here? Is there a better way to convert a .dat or .txt two dimensional data to a two dimensional array of doubles in C++?

Comment: Does your file contain 4x400 data or more?

Comment: So you have 4000 col's and 4 row's ?

Comment: Oops, I meant 4 columns 4000 rows. I fixed that in my CDTable.h, but I have the same issue.

Comment: My .dat file has 4 col's and 4001 rows, but that includes that first line of column titles, which is why I skip a line before entering the loop.

Comment: lol, I think I got it.

Comment: while (getline(file, line, '\t')). The delimiter should not go into getline. That was creating 4*4000 "lines", not "4000" lines of 4 entries separated by the delimiter.

Comment: your dat file is with 4000 lines of 4 fields or with 4 lines with 4000 fields?

Comment: It is 4000 lines of 4 fields. The original header file got that wrong. The problem remained even after fixing that around; the delimiter in my getline was unnecessary/wrong. Getting rid of that fixed the issue. Thanks everyone anyways :)

Comment: That's the problem (I suppose). Try changing `double table[4][4000];` with `double table[4000][4];`. Or switching `row` with `col`.

Comment: Yup I did that as soon as zahir pointed that out. Thanks!